# Pass variable between two different interpreters in Zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm using %phoenix interpreter in zeppelin 0.60 and I have executed a SQL statement , my question is how can I get this result in a variable and then use it in my python interpreter so I can do some pandas manipulation with it ?

Or maybe this scenario is not supported ?

Comment: did you get an answer for this? I'm facing the same issue.